# Google charts - Control Wrappers fails on Ajax

Tags: google-visualization

I am using google charts to build a graph. Everything is working fine when loaded through browser.

I have different tabs which shows different data on click. I am using ajax to get the data and the graph works fine too, because i use

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(data));
```

on success.

I am using `google.visualization.Dashboard` to make use of `control wrapper` and `chart wrapper` The control wrapper helps me to get the slider kind of thing which filters within the graph. And this works fine when loaded through browser. However on ajax load i am getting the slider change in values but it doesn't show the slider HTML.

what else need to be passed to achieve this when loaded through ajax ???

Let me know if anything needed !!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thought it might help someone on this.

The google load initializer i was recalling on every ajax request, wherein this needs to be loaded only once.

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["controls",'corechart']});
```

So i used this above the dom ready statement.